# Data visualization tool for transactions in a Map

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

What data visualization tools should I consider using to make something like this [Obama | One People visualization](http://senseable.mit.edu/obama/the_world.html)?

[image: Screenshot of visualization]

ComponentArt has [something similar](http://dv2011.componentart.com/#/Views/DemoViewPage.xaml$control=Maps&category=Feature_Highlights&demo=Time%E2%80%93driven_Plotting), but it only show points; I want to draw lines to represent relationships between points.

I'd prefer a solution that uses WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, after 4 years of your questions, there are rich tools to visualize map and curves on it.
Java Script tools:

- [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-curved-lines/?theme=none)
- [Any Charts](https://www.anychart.com/products/anymap/gallery/Maps_Connectors/)
- [Data Matic](http://datamatic.io/)

Hope my answer will be useful after more than 4 years :)